How can I extract the font from a bslib theeme?
I would like to extract the different fonts from a theme that are created by bslib. There is a function called bs_get_variables but i does not seem to return any font-familes.
vars <- c("body-bg", "body-color", "primary", "border-radius", "font-family", "base_font", "code_font", "heading_font")
bs_get_variables(bs_theme(bootswatch = "sketchy"), varnames = vars)


See the documentation at https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/bs5-variables/index.html
library(bslib)
vars <- c("body-bg", "body-color", "primary", "border-radius", "font-family-sans-serif", "font-family-monospace", "font-family-base", "headings-font-family", "font-family-code")
bs_get_variables(bs_theme(bootswatch = "sketchy"), varnames = vars)

Gives:
                                                                                                            body-bg 
                                                                                                             "#fff" 
                                                                                                         body-color 
                                                                                                          "#212529" 
                                                                                                            primary 
                                                                                                             "#333" 
                                                                                                      border-radius 
                                                                                                             "25px" 
                                                                                             font-family-sans-serif 
"Neucha, -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", Roboto, \"Helvetica Neue\", Arial, sans-serif" 
                                                                                              font-family-monospace 
                         "SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", \"Courier New\", monospace" 
                                                                                                   font-family-base 
                                                                                        "var(--bs-font-sans-serif)" 
                                                                                               headings-font-family 
                                                                                        "\"Cabin Sketch\", cursive" 
                                                                                                   font-family-code 
                                                                                         "var(--bs-font-monospace)" 


It seems the bslib package by default does not return a function that exposes the font of a particular theme. However, you can still see the font used in a theme by running the code below:
bs_theme_preview(bs_theme())

This will launch a Shiny app, like the one in the image below, from which you can see the font used in the theme, as well as other CSS properties.

You can see the fonts used in the theme in the corner in the blue square.
